# How do I swap fragments in and out of my app?

Tags: android, android-fragments, notifications, android-framelayout

I have been following the tutorial [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html):
And this code here has been confusing me:

```
    /** Swaps fragments in the main content view */
    private void selectItem(int position) {
    // Create a new fragment and specify the planet to show based on position
    Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
               .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
               .commit();

    // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
    mDrawer.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawer);
```

Right now my app runs and looks great, but when you press on the buttons in the navigation drawer, nothing happens. I need to figure out how that if a user presses one button, it swaps in a new `FrameLayout`. Also another question: I have this in my `activity_main.xml` layout:

```
<!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
<FrameLayout  android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"> 
<ListView 
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:keepScreenOn="true"
>

    </ListView>

</FrameLayout>

<!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container. A solid background is used for contrast
     with the content view. -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
```

I'm not entirely sure if I should have my list view with the content in it yet (the `ListView` inside of the `FrameLayout`). I tried making its own `xml` layout but when I refrenced it to inflate the `ListView` it didn't work. So do i set up a separate 'xml' file for each frame? If so, how do I swap in that fragment based on what button is clicked? Thanks for your time and help!

EDIT!!
THIS IS THE SELECTITEM METHOD

```
    private void selectItem(int position) {     

    Log.i("MainActivity", "selectItem()" + position);  //this gets called successfully

    //not sure if this equals() thing is the best way to do this
    if("Stuff".equals(getListView().getItemAtPosition(position))){

        Log.i("MainActivity", "getItemAtPosition()-Stuff" + position); //this doesn't get called

        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

    }else if("Stuff2".equals(getListView().getItemAtPosition(position))){

        Log.i("MainActivity", "getItemAtPosition()-Stuff2" + position); //this also doesn't get called

        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

        Intent openHelpAvtivity = new Intent("com.schrodingerscat.hh.math.glossary.THEOREMSLIST");
        startActivity(openHelpAvtivity); 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried stepping through it with a debugger? Is selectItem() getting called? If not, make sure that you set the OnClickListener correctly.

You don't need separate XML files for each frame. (What do you mean by frame? Fragment? I'm assuming so.) The whole point is that you can create a new fragment and use setArguments() to set what it displays. The list view should have its data populated with the following code, as provided:

```
    mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // Set the adapter for the list view
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
```

Try downloading the full example code (http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/NavigationDrawer.zip) and see what you're doing differently. I think that this example is meant to be downloaded, not reconstructed: the tutorial page doesn't quite include all the code that you need.

Comment: I'm trying to get the list view items that appear to do something when you tap them, which will then set the fragment. I have tried a lot of different stuff. I tried `if("mars".equals(getListView().getItemAtPosition(position))){}` to no avail. I'm no expert.

Comment: OK, that above line of code isn't how you're supposed to do it -- the line you're supposed to use is:
mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

And then the DrawerItemClickListener handles everything.

Do you know how to use a debugger? I would really recommend it. If not, either learn (yay!) or use logging statements (super easy) to figure out whether or not the onClickListener's selectItem() method was called.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! Yay! Thanks to @bee for the enlightenment! All i had to do, instead of using getListView(), I did this instead: `if("Stuff".equals(mDrawerList.getItemAtPosition(position))){}` and that finally worked!